# Function change text does not work if I add font awesome

Tags: function, font-awesome, innerhtml, getelementbyid

This is my function that takes the id from my button and changes the text:

```
var modal_button_update = document.getElementById("modal_button_text");
if (modal_button_update.innerHTML === "Add") { modal_button_update.innerHTML = "Update"; }
```

It's working fine with this button (Add becomes Update)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text">Add</button>
```

But for some reason it does not change anymore if I try to add a font awesome icon:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</button>
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code. It seems the problem is that you are checking if your `modal_button_update` button's innerHTML is equal to Add. The original button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text">Add</button>
```

works because the innerHTML of your `modal_button_update` is exactly 'Add', but your modified `modal_button_update`: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</button>` does not work because the innerHTML is `<i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>&gt;Add` which is not equal (===) to 'Add'.

Here's three different ways I chose to solve this issue:

1. Remove the `<i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true">` element and place the font-awesome icon inside the button class like: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group fas fa-save" id="modal_button_text">Add</button>`
   `
2. Alter your Javascript to look something like: `var modal_button_update = document.getElementById("modal_button_text"); if (modal_button_update.innerHTML.includes("Add")) { modal_button_update.innerHTML = "Update"; }`
   Here the button checks to see if the innerHTML *contains* 'Add'.
3. ***Keeping the font-awesome icon***:
   In the two solutions above, your Javascript code will strip the button element of the font-awesome class when successfully changing the innerHTML to 'Update'. It is, *imo*, easier to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to alter the value of the button to solve this issue like:

---*HTML*---

```
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</button>
```

---*Javascript*--

```
if ($('#modal_button_text').html().includes("Add")) {
    $('#modal_button_text').html("Update");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to keep the icon no matter the state of the text (i.e., Add or Update), I would personally enclose the word "Add" in a span as follows:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_button add_group" id="modal_button_text"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="modal_button_span">Add</span></button>
```

Then it is just a matter of whether you use jQuery or not as to which of the following will work for you.

JavaScript:

Change value based on current text:

```
if(document.getElementById("modal_button_span").innerHTML === "Add")  document.getElementById("modal_button_span").innerHTML = "Update";
```

Toggle value when the button is clicked based on current text:

```
document.getElementById("modal_button_span").innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_button_span").innerHTML === "Add" ? "Update" : "Add";
```

jQuery:

Change value based on current text:

```
if($("#modal_button_span").html() === "Add") $("#modal_button_span").html("Update");
```

Toggle value when the button is clicked based on current text:

```
$("#modal_button_span").html($("#modal_button_span").html() === "Add" ? "Update" : "Add");
```

By enclosing the word Add in a span, you are free to do whatever you need to the text without disrupting the rest of the button or save icon.

Comment: Just a note: Caleb F. did a great job explaining the why, so I felt there was no need to go over again.